# How can i change checkbox in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

How can i set a check box to true or false.. I have tried all of these combinations:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'prefs[can_be_email_notified]', :id => 'user_preferences_can_email'%> Email 
<%= check_box_tag 'prefs[can_be_email_notified]', '', :id => 'user_preferences_can_email'%> Email
<%= check_box_tag 'prefs[can_be_email_notified]', '', :checked =>'',:id => 'user_preferences_can_email'%> Email
```

tried to change the checkbox with these

```
document.getElementById("user_preferences_can_email").checked = true;
document.getElementById("user_preferences_can_email").value = true;
document.getElementById("user_preferences_can_email").checked.value = true;
```

Maybe i wasnt clear...

I have a set of values that are set to buttons and want to change the checkbox's to be checked or unchecked detirmed on the value set on the the button,

ie:

```
function doubleClickUser(can_email, can_screen) {
        document.getElementById("user_preferences_can_email").checked = can_email;
        document.getElementById("user_preferences_can_screen").checked = can_screen;
}

<button class="button" onclick="doubleClickUser('true','false')"><%= user[:email] %></button>

<%= check_box_tag 'prefs[can_be_email_notified]', :id => 'user_preferences_can_email'%> Email
<%= check_box_tag 'prefs[can_be_screen_notified]', :id => 'user_preferences_can_screen' %> Screen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the field's value in your controller or model, then simply include the element in the standard Rails form:

```
# controller
@pref = Pref.new (or Pref.find(params[:id])

# view
<%= form_for @pref do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :can_be_email_notified %>
  <%= f.check_box :can_be_email_notified %>
<% end %>
```

This will reflect whatever value of `can_be_email_notified` @pref has.

Comment: I would do that... but this is being sent over by an api and setting values in a custom model. cant use the form_for helper since this form is functioning as an api... no data stored locally

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be checked try this:

```
EMAIL
<%= check_box_tag "email",params[:email].to_s  , {:checked => true}  %>
```

Also if you want to assing a value you can try this:

```
<%= check_box_tag "email", "5", params[:email].to_s == "5", {:checked => true}  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out you have to set the status to `false` first

```
<%= check_box_tag 'prefs[can_be_email_notified]', '', false, :id => 'user_preferences_can_email' %> Email <br>
<%= check_box_tag 'prefs[can_be_screen_notified]', '', false, :id => 'user_preferences_can_screen' %> Screen <br>
<%= check_box_tag 'prefs[can_be_sms_notified]', '', false, :id => 'user_preferences_can_sms' %> Text </div></th>
```